# What is the correct software to open a .tar file?

Tags: tar

I want to be able to play the game [N](http://www.thewayoftheninja.org/n.html), but I can't figure out what to use other than 
archive manager to open it.

[Here is the link to the game download](http://www.thewayoftheninja.org/n.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A .tar file is an archive, similar to a .zip file. It is compressed. As with a .zip file, you have to extract (decompress) the contents.

You can extract the contents with any of several graphical tools, archive manager is fine, or from the command line as follows;

`tar -xvf your.tar`

[Here are a few more examples of using the tar command](http://www.tecmint.com/18-tar-command-examples-in-linux/).

Usually there will be a README explaining how to use the contents of the archive to play your game. Once you have finished extracting your archive, the contents may or may not need to be compiled. [Here is a quick guide on compiling an application on Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo).

Comment: the last link you put does not work. As in it says "This page does not exist." It worked for me at first but when I went back and clicked it that popped up. Just so you know.

Comment: @ bodhi.zazen it works now, thanks! I'm still working on it but I will have it done soon.

Comment: Note that the files in a tar archive are not compressed.  They are simply bundled together into one file.  As is the *nix way, there is a separate utility to compress files but it only works on one file at a time.  This is why it is common to see archives that are also compressed labeled with file.tar.gz